# Weird behaviour of linq method .All()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In my Asp.Net.Core 2.0 MVC project I have a problem.
This method returns true even when I know for sure it shouldn't.

```
private ApplicationDbContext _context;

private bool AreAllEmailsSent(DateTime deadline)
    {
        return _context.Users
            .Where(u => u.EmailConfirmed)
            .All(u => u.LastEmailSent > deadline);
    }
```

The weirdest part is when I put .ToList() it returns false which is correct in my unit test

```
private bool AreAllEmailsSent(DateTime deadline)
{
    return _context.Users
        .Where(u => u.EmailConfirmed).ToList()
        .All(u => u.LastEmailSent > deadline);
}
```

There is no compile error or warning. I know that

```
_context.Users.Where()
```

is an IQueriable of ApplicationUsers.
I know it's a broad question but can somebody explain why this happens? It looks very dangerous to me.

Comment: linq is evaluated lazily; doing tolist forces it to be evaluated there and then; that might have something to do with it

Comment: That means there's a difference in the date comparison in your DB and in C#.  What DB are you using?  What is the exact date you pass to the method and the dates in the table?

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama No, `All` will also make it evaluate.  The difference is that the first part is translated to SQL and run on the DB while the second does the `All` check in memory.

Comment: It may also help if you could capture the SQL generated in the first example.

Comment: I'm using in memory DbContext SqlServer for my unit testing. I pass in  DateTime deadline = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: @Jones Can I assume that all the dates in the table are well within the last 7 days then?

Comment: No it is 7 days for sure

Comment: There is a date that is older than the deadline so it should return false. With and without .ToList() I get a different outcome

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is a difference like the DB column being a DATE so it doesnt' include the time portion in the comparison.

Comment: I don't know how EF handles `NULL` and translates `All`, but in C#, `(DateTime?) null > DateTime.Now` is `false`, while in SQL, `NULL > GETDATE()` is `NULL`/undefined. The former would count when checking "true for all", the latter might not.

Comment: I changed assigned the dateTime so it isn't null with:  public DateTime LastEmailSent { get; set; } = new DateTime(); Still no luck

Comment: Then maybe it's time to dig in and see what SQL queries EF is actually generating. One of them should yield rows, while the other does not.

Comment: You can use LINQPad to help with examining generated SQL and debugging LINQ. If you put `.Where(u => u.LastEmailSent != null)` in both queries, do they then return the same answer?